# Chrome 41 ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH Tomcat 7

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, tomcat7

Since I have updated Chrome from Version 40 to 41, I no longer can access my ssl site running in a local tomcat 7 instance. I have a self signed certificate.

Chrome just prints `This webpage is not available` together with `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

I already tried the `chrome://flags` switch `Minimum SSL/TLS version supported` to `SSLv3`, which did not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Java EE web application running with a self signed certificate on Wildfly 8.1.

You are probably using a 1024 bit DSA public key with your selfsigned certificate and Chrome stops/stopped supporting DSA(DSS).

Creating a RSA 2048 certificate and using it with your web application should solve your problem.

Comment: @NoCatharsis There is no such thing as a "complete response". There'll be always someone who lacks knowledge of a part in the process. It's not helpful to explain the creation of certificates and every other step in it's entirety and full granularity at this point for the same reason as it's out of place to describe how to use a console or to copy files. Once you know it's required to create the mentioned certificate, you can research on [how to do that](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=How+to+create+a+RSA+certificate).

Comment: Currently in 2023, only **Firefox** support **secp521r1**. Other browsers **(Edge/Chrome/Opera)** doesn't support **secp521r1, sect, brainpoolP, c2tnb**.
For maximum compatibility, you can use: **rsa, secp384r1, prime256v1**.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt its an SSL/TLS protocol version problem. Most of the time this error means the server and client couldn't agree on which cipher to use. Take a look at this blog post: https://blog.eveoh.nl/2014/02/tls-ssl-ciphers-pfs-tomcat/ on how to enable a secure and compatible cipher suite in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

In the Tomcat `server.xml` file you can set `ciphers` attribute in the SSL/TLS `<connector/>` element.

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,
         TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,
         SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"
```

This solved the problem in my case for `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` in Chromium / Chrome and for `ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap` in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you came here from Google and since this is the highest ranking 'ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH' entry:

another explanation is that you started an nodejs https or express server with invalid or empty credentials. The irritating bit is that the server starts without complaining and ssl seems to work, but the negotiation between browser and server fails with this error.