# Tomcat8 SSL connector

Tags: ssl, https, configuration, java-8, tomcat8

I followed the [official tutorial](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) to install ssl on tomcat8 but my browser is giving me a **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH** error.

First of all I give you the informations about the server :

- ip : 10.1.5.55
- Tomcat port : 8200
- Java version : 1.8.0_121
- Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/8.5.11
- Servlet Specification Version : 3.1
- JSP version : 2.3

I use `https://10.1.5.55:8200/` as url to connect to my server (which is working with the http protocol)

The first thing which confused me was the fact that all tutorial are talking about connector like :

```
<Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="8443" .../>
```

But the basic config file server.xml provides me this template :

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" >
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeyFile="conf/localhost-rsa-key.pem"
                         certificateFile="conf/localhost-rsa-cert.pem"
                         certificateChainFile="conf/localhost-rsa-chain.pem"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Anyway I followed up the tutorial and generated my keystore under E:\keys :

```
keytool -genkey -alias myapp -keystore myapp-keystore
```

In First and Last Name I typed : 10.1.5.55:8200
Password : changeit
I pressed return to get the same password for the key.

Then I wrote my connector like it (I modified the http port to run on 8199) :

```
<Connector
    port="8200" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    SSLEnabled="true" 
    maxThreads="300" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true" 
    clientAuth="false" 
    sslProtocol="TLS" 
    keystoreFile="E:\keys\myapp-keystore" 
    keystorePass="changeit"
/>
```

But I got the error at this point.

Now there are all solutions I tried :

- try one by one all TLS protocol (v1, v1.1, v1.2, SSLv3)
- Change first and last name of keystore by 10.1.5.55 lonely
- try protocol="HTTP/1.1", protocol org...Http11Nio2Protocol

And finally I tried to add ciphers. Here is the list I used :

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, 
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, 
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSVF 
"
```

I got this list [from here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/659) and here I learned that Tomcat7 w/ Java7 works differently than Tomcat8 w/ Java8. I tried, as it's recommended here, to remove "sslProtocol" and add "useServerCipherSuitesOrder" but nothing worked, always the same error from my browser.

Please someone can tell me how to solves this ?

Comment: Could you try to add `keystoreAlias="myapp"` to `<Connector` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added it with my basic configuration I provided + ciphers and it doesn't work

Comment: try to remove port number from the common name of the certificate. Set only your IP 10.1.5.55 ( i do not know if this can be the issue. Usually is used the name of the domain)

Comment: I kept the keystoreAlias and regenerated my keystore with the ip only but again the same error

Comment: Try to generate a RSA certificate of 2048 bits instead of a DSA certificate of 1024 . Use `keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore myapp-keystore`
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207397/6371459

Comment: Thanks it was the issue ! Please provide me a simple answer that I can accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating a DSA certificate of 1024 bits and Chrome stops/stopped supporting DSA(DSS) as shown also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29207397/6371459) or [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/eu4Za4dXHhQ). Try to generate a RSA certificate of 2048 bits

Replace this command

```
keytool -genkey -alias myapp -keystore myapp-keystore
```

with

```
keytool -genkey -alias myapp -keystore myapp-keystore -keyalg RSA
```